# Google Sheets Scripts getCurrentCell()

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Scripts and need help finding a solution to the following code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

// Returns the current highlighted cell in the one of the active ranges.

var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
```

When I save it, it does not let me run the script. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: To execute code, it must be contained within a function. All non-enclosed code is executed only as a part of an instance execution, i.e. when a function is executed. Review https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script

Comment: Thank you, what type of function would you recommend for the code?

Comment: @manuelordaz Just wrap it in a `function () {  /* your code */}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this -

```
function getCurrentCellValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  // do what you need to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would I follow the same concept for the following one?

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A1").Value = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the language you're writing.